# Flutter : Post request with credentials

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I make post requests from flutter.I need to authenticate a user with his email address and password. Please help

tried with the following code

```
 http.post(url, body: {"email": "email", "password": "password"})
      .then((response) {
    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    //print("Response body: ${response.body}");
  });
```

getting "firewall read failed or timeout" error

Comment: firewall read failed or timeout - this sounds like a network problem.

Comment: but I am running on my physical device

Comment: Could you post the log of the error including stacktrace? That might help. Also, could you try doing a http.get from whichever server you're trying to access, as that can tell us you're having a problem accessing the server or with the actual request you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:io'
    show HttpClient, HttpClientBasicCredentials, HttpClientCredentials;

import 'package:http/http.dart' show BaseClient, IOClient;

typedef Future<bool> HttpAuthenticationCallback(
    Uri uri, String scheme, String realm);

HttpAuthenticationCallback _basicAuthenticationCallback(
        HttpClient client, HttpClientCredentials credentials) =>
    (Uri uri, String scheme, String realm) {
      client.addCredentials(uri, realm, credentials);
      return new Future.value(true);
    };

BaseClient createBasicAuthenticationIoHttpClient(
    String userName, String password) {
  final credentials = new HttpClientBasicCredentials(userName, password);

  final client = new HttpClient();
  client.authenticate = _basicAuthenticationCallback(client, credentials);
  return new IOClient(client);
}
```

```
final http =
    createBasicAuthenticationIoHttpClient(_config.userName, _config.password);

http.get(...)
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: And how handle 401 status?

Comment: @Augusto what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have a rest API (in ruby on rails) with return 401 when it's unauthorized (user not have access to the specified area, for example). If I use 400 error in this backend, flutter handle perfectly, but not in 401

Comment: Interesting. I don't remember in what context I used this exactly. I think it was to access some Graph database server (Virtuoso or Stardog). I don't know what they respond with. Did you check https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519413/dart-client-httprequest-error-authentication-handling, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305479/dart-httpclient-with-basic-authentication-issues-after-flutter-upgrade might also help.